# Positive even integers dense in the p-adic integers

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

On page 22 of the book *p-adic Numbers, p-adic Analysis, and Zeta-Functions* by Koblitz, it says that the set $S$ of positive even integers is "dense" in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ when $p>2$.

This seems very strange to me. Take for example $3\in \mathbb{Z}_3$. How is this the limit of a sequence of positive even integers?

Comment: For your example, take the sequence $3^n+3$. Then $|(3^n+3)-3|_3 = 3^{-n} \to 0$, so it converges to $3$.

Comment: I see, many thanks! How would one prove this in general? The p-adic integer $1+3+9+\cdots\in \mathbb{Z}_3$ also does not have an obvious (to me) sequence that limits to it.

Comment: @Erik: you can take the sequence $1 + 3, 1 + 3 + 9 + 27, \dots$. In general, first try to prove that $\mathbb{Z}$ is dense in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ for any $p$, then try to modify this proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the general case:

Let $\sum_{j\ge0}a_jp^j\in \Bbb Z_p$. Let $b_n=\sum_{j=0}^na_jp^j$. Consider the sequence given by
$$
c_n = \begin{cases}b_n & b_n\textrm{ even} \\ b_n + p^{n+1} & b_n\textrm{ odd} \end{cases}
$$
.

Comment: I see, many thanks!

Comment: @ErikBarinaga No problem :) If you’re satisfied with an answer, you’re encouraged to accept it (with the green tick mark), so other users can see that it’s closed. If not, you’re free to ask questions or request additional details

Comment: Hi @Milten how it can be seen that $N$ is dense in p-adic integers?

Comment: @Bestmat That could be taken as a corollary of the above, since a superset of a dense subset is always dense. Or indeed, you can simplify the above proof by using $b_n$ directly instead of introducing $c_n$ as well.